# what is the usage of response setContent in laravel index file?

Tags: php, laravel

I started to develope some new feature on old laravel project from another developer that i don't have access to him
I saw some modification in index.php that I never seen this before
what is the usage on this code in index.php in public folder

```
 $response->setContent($response->content());
```

can I delete it?
this single line of code is reason of some problem in my project

Comment: You have to check what $response returns here

Comment: so you say that i should check each endpint in the project  ?

Comment: Did you try to use " use Illuminate\Http\Request;"  instead of 
"use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request;" ?

Answer (score 0):

If I were you in this case I will remove it to see it fails, then trace the failure and decide if there is a need for this line or not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).